# AngularJS ResponseError Inspector call refresh token - impementation

Tags: angularjs, token, http-status-code-401, jwt, inspector

Can some one please provide a working sample of AngularJS refresh web token call from Inspector responseError method when get the status code = 401.

I tried some of the ways that are given in some forums, but seems to be nothing is working for me. Here is my inspector. Thanks in advance.

```html
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("myapp")
         .factory("myAuthInterceptor", ['$window', '$q', function ($window, $q) {
             var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};
             var _request = function (config) {
                 config.headers = config.headers || {};
                 var authData = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
                 var temp = JSON.parse(authData).split('&');
                 var accessToken = temp[0];
                 if (accessToken) {
                     config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
                 }
                 return config;
             }

             var _responseError = function (response) {
                 if ((response.status === 401) && (response.statusText === 'Invalid Token')) {

                     var url = "http://10.1.1.6/api/token/refresh";
                     var authData = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
                     var temp = JSON.parse(authData).split('&');
                     var refreshToken = temp[1];
     
// How would i get the call to refresh token and get the new access Token then retry my last call.
                    

                 }
                 return $q.reject(response);
             }

             authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
             authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;
             return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
         }]);


}());
```

How would i get the call to refresh token and get the new access Token then retry my last call.